# JS map array to return object of arrays for React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

If I want to return an array of objects from a nested array in JS/React, what would be the way to do this? I have tried the following, but this gives an error about react children - objects cant be rendered as children try an array.

data:

```
{
      "title": 0,
      "name": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "summary": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "start": "2019-11-01",
          "end": "2019-11-04"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "start": "2019-11-01",
          "end": "2019-11-04"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have tried:

```
const newArray = result?.summary?.map((inner: any) => {
    return (
        {
            from: new Date(inner?.start),
            to: new Date(inner?.end),
            label: {
                text: (inner?.id),
            },
         }
    )
})
```

I want to create a new array of objects with the data from the `summary` nested array?

any idea's?

Comment: There's no need to optional chain `inner`. Either there's an array to map over in which case inner will exist, or there's no array to map over.

Comment: There will be no `map` operation if there's no array.  If there's an array ([even if it's empty](https://jsfiddle.net/0kgxs5ya/)) `inner` is the element that's used on the current iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue. You need to convert your `dates` to `strings`. The third-party package you input this array tries to render the Date objects and fails to do so. The date is `object type` and that is what the error is all about.

Try this:

```
const newArray = result?.summary?.map((inner: any) => {
    return (
        {
            from: new Date(inner?.start).toString(),
            to: new Date(inner?.end).toString(),
            label: {
                text: (inner?.id),
            },
         }
    )
})
```

Use `toDateString` to get a formatted date string.

Comment: I suggest using `toISOString().slice(0, 10)` to match the OP's original values.